# Why unmodifiableList in Collections parameter is <? extends T>

Tags: java, collections

There is the [`unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) method in the `Collections` class. It returns a `List<T>` but in the parameters it accepts `List<? extends T>`.

So if I understand this right then this method accepts a List which has T objects or objects that inherited from T class.
But I don't understand why the `<? extends T>` part in the parameter. I mean the parameter determines the return type of the method. If the method is called with `List<Animal>` then the return will be `List<Animal>` so it is going to be the same. Why we need this `<? extends T>?` Why don't we need just `List<T>` in the parameter list? I don't understand this.

If you could provide an example I would be happy about it.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> So if I understand this right then this method accepts a List which has T objects or objects that inherited from T class

This is oversimplifying matters.

a `List<Number>` can contain solely integers. The point of a `List<Number>` is that it is constrained to contain only number instances. Not that each instance MUST be Number and specifically Number - that would be impossible, as `Number` is abstract (no instances of Number itself can possibly exist, only instances of some subclass of it). The only difference between a `List<Integer>` containing only integers and a `List<Number>` containing only integers, is that you can add, say, a `Double` instance to that `List<Number>`, but you can't add it to a `List<Integer>`.

Because a method that takes, as argument, a `List<Something>` **could** invoke `.add()`, the type system needs to worry about the difference. It needs to do so **even if** this method does not, in fact, call `add` at all, and never intends to. The type system doesn't know that, and you're free to change the body of a method in some future version without that breaking backwards compatibility, thus, it matters. Even if you feel like it does not.

That then also explains your question:

If you have some method that demands a `List<Number>`, then you may provide a `List<Integer>` to `Collections.unmodifiableList`, and that's fine - Collections.uL will give you that `List<Number>`. This would ordinarily be broken, in that you can invoke `.add(someDouble)` which you should not be doing to a list of integers, but `.add` doesn't work on an unmodifiable, so it's fine.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that I can call the unmodifiableList this way:
```var unModifiableList = Collections.<Dog>unmodifiableList(dogs);```
I didn't know that I can specify the type when invoking it. I always called without specifying the type at invoking so I didn't get it because I thought that the parameter and the return type is always going to be the same so why we have this ```? extend T``` but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

`List<? extends T>` means it also accepts lists of subtypes.

Imagine having a class `Plant` and a class `Tree` that extends `Plant`.

You could create an unmodifiable `List` of `Plant`s using a `List<Tree>` because `Collections.unmodifiableList` accepts lists of any subtype of `T`.

If it was `List<T>`, it would accept a `List<Plant>` as a parameter in order to create an unmodifiable `List<Plant>` but you could not create an unmodifiable `List<Plant>` using a `List<Tree>` as parameter.